# Python - Pulling data from a file that matches a parameter

Tags: python

I have a file that contains information about users and the amount of times they have logged in. I am trying to pull all users that have a login of >= 250 and save it to another file. I am new at python coding and continue to get a "invalid literal with base 10" error when trying to run this portion of my code. Can anyone help me out and explain why this happens so I can prevent from this from happening in the future? TIA
thanks

```
def main():
  userInformation = readfile("info")
  suspicious = []
  for i in userInformation :
    if(int(i[2])>=250):
       suspicious.append(i)
```

Full code below if needed:

```
#Reading the file function
def readFile(filename):
    file = open(filename,'r')
    lines =  [x.split('\n')[0].split(';') for x in file.readlines()]
    file.close()
    return lines

def writeFile(suspicious):
 
    file = open('suspicious.txt','w')
    for i in suspicious:
        
        file.write('{};{};{};{}\n'.format(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3]))
   
    file.close()

def main()
   userInformation = readfile("info")
   suspicious = []
   for i in userInformation :
     if(int(i[2])>=250):
       suspicious.append(i)
   writeFile(suspicious)
   
   print('Suspicious users:')
   for i in suspicious:
      print('{} {}'.format(i[0],i[1]))
main()
```

Here is some line of my file:

Jodey;Lamins;278

Chris;Taylors;113

David;Mann;442
etc
etc

Comment: share some line of your file

Answer (score 0):

"invalid literal with base 10" occurs when you're trying to parse an integer that's not in base 10. In other words i[2] is not a valid integer (most likely it's a string that you're incorrectly trying to convert to an integer). Also, it would be best to correctly format your main function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was under the idea that the "int" portion would take care of this? Since I am passing a string to an interger?

Comment: So the problem is, the "int" portion is, as you said, **trying** to take care of it. However, it's not a parseable string. For example, something like int("hello world") wouldn't work, because the string "hello world" isn't a valid base 10 integer. That's why it'd be helpful to see some of your file data like Belhadjer Samir said, so we can see where it can't parse.

Comment: Alright, so what fixed it for me was just deleting the extra pair of brackets (i[3])  in your file.write() call. The fourth parameter doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I took your example file and played with it a little. The issues I faced were mostly spacing issues. So, here's the code you might like -

```
UsersInfoFileName = '/path/to/usersinfofile.txt'
MaxRetries = 250
usersWithExcessRetries = []

with open(UsersInfoFileName, 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  consecutiveLines = (line.strip() for line in lines if line.strip())
  for line in consecutiveLines:
    if (int(line.split(';')[-1]) > MaxRetries):
      usersWithExcessRetries.append(line)

for suspUsers in usersWithExcessRetries:
  print(suspUsers)
```

Here's what it does -

- Reads all lines in the given file
- Filters all lines by excluding lines which may be empty
- Removes surrounding white spaces for the remaining lines
- Reads last semi-colon separated value, and compares it with MaxRetries
- Adds the original line to a list if the value exceeds MaxRetries